# Xcode: Remove an array of textiews from screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, textview

I'm currently adding 5 textviews onto the viewcontroller programatically inside the viewDidLoad method.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    //Add 5 textviews

    UITextView *reqTV = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30,30,250,50)];
    reqTV.text = @"This is a textview";
    [self.view addSubview:reqTV];
}
```

If later, I want to delete (not hide) these 5 textviews with a button click, how would I do that?

I have thought of using this, but am not sure how to call all 5 textviews to delete them.

```
- (void)removeTextViewButton:(id)sender {
    [reqTV removeFromSuperview]; //remove textview
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two easy ways:

1. You can save your textViews inside array as ivar of your controller.

And later remove each textView in array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  ...
  [textViews addObject: reqTV];
  ...
}
- (void)removeTextViewButton:(UIButton *)sender {
  [textViews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
}
```

2. Assign static tag for each textView:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  ...
  reqTV.tag = 1001; // for example
}
- (void)removeTextViewButton:(UIButton *)sender {
  NSArray *subs = [NSArray arrayWithArray: self.view.subviews];
  for (UIView *sub in subs) {
    if (sub.tag == 1001) {
      [sub removeFromSuperview];
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding `UITextField`s on viewController use tag value to uniquely identify each textField.

You can store each tag value in an array for further use, eg.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *tagArray;

NSMutableArray *tagArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 101; i <= 105; i++ ) {
    UITextField *txt = [UITextField alloc] init]; //for eg.
    ...
    ...
    txt.tag = i;
    [arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
    [self.view addSubView:txt];
}
```

When you want to delete any of the textField or all then...

```
UIView *view = [self.view viewWithTag:<tag value>];
[view removeFromSuperview];
```

eg.

```
for (int i = 0; i < tagArray.count; i++) {
    NSInteger tag = [[arr objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
    UITextField *txt = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:tag];
    [txt removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Used code below to remove `UITextView`s:

```
- (void)removeTextViewButton:(id)sender {
  NSArray *reqTVViews = [NSArray arrayWithArray: self.view.subviews];
  for (UIView *tvView in reqTVViews) {
    if ([tvView isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]) {
      [tvView removeFromSuperview];
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all subview in one go

```
- (void)removeTextViewButton:(id)sender 
 {
    for (UIView *subview in views.subviews)
        {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }
 }
```

Happy Coding.. :)